# Override Team City Environment variable setting

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

We have a Team City Unit test build which we call using $(teamcity_dotnet_nunitlauncher) through different MSBuild scripts. The build has an environment variable set up. Is there a way we can override the variable through the scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are "published" as MSBuild properties, so for example:

```
$(COMPUTERNAME)
```

...will give the value of that env var.  You can override any property inside an MSBuild script...

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <COMPUTERNAME>NewName</COMPUTERNAME>
</PropertyGroup>
```

...or pass it in on the command line to MSBuild...

```
> msbuild My.proj /t:Target /p:COMPUTERNAME=NewName
```

These two ways to alter the "property" presented by an environment variable are not equal though, when passing a property via the command line, the value will not be overridden if it is declared in an MSBuild file.